# Can't access Tomcat Manager unless I'm in localhost

Tags: java, tomcat

If I go to localhost:8080 I can access Tomcat Manager. But If I'm at another computer and I access 192.168.25.81:8080 it says "Resource not Available", everything else works fine. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Do you have the port open?

Comment: Yes, I can access anything in the webapps folder.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you're in the same network? Is the device connected correctly?

If you are then please add more information because the problem isn't really clear

```
http://{host}:{port}
```

Comment: Yes I am. I have a project called "NF", if I go to "192.168.25.81:8080/NF/index.jsp" it works perfectly fine however if I simply go to 192.168.25.81:8080 it returns "Resource not Available".

Comment: You sure it only returns "Resource not Available" ? You sure have the permissions on other devices to run the files?

Comment: What do you mean by permission on other devices?

Comment: Your host"192.168.25.81:8080" might have firewall/file permissions that makes other devices unable to read the files

Comment: There is no firewall on that computer.